# Extending rational sections of tangent bundle

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a Fano manifold of dimension $n$ and of Picard number one. Let $U$ be an open subset of $X$ such that $TU$ is generated by $n$ commuting sections sections $s_1, s_2, ..., s_n$. Here commuting sections means the Lie bracket of any pair of sections is zero. Let $p \in X \setminus U$, such that all the rational curves through $p$ are free.

Question: Is it possible to extend these rational sections of $TX$ to $U \cup \{p\}$ such that $s_1(p), s_2(p), ..., s_n(p)$ generates the tangent space at $p$ ?